# SelectedIndexChanged called before class constructor in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, selectedvalue, selectedindexchanged

I create a class in my c# application called Acquisti.
Then I initialize it in form constructor and then I call a method of this class in combobox SelectedIndexChanged event.
The problem is that when I run the program I get an error that says that the object of the Acquisti class that I created is null. This means that SelectedIndexChanged event is called before than form constructor, isn't it? I also tried with SelectedValueChanged event but I have the same problem. Here is the simple code:

```
Acquisti _acquisti;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        for (int i = DateTime.Now.Year; i >= 2000; i--)
            annoAcquisti.Items.Add(i);

        annoAcquisti.SelectedIndex = 0;

        _acquisti = new Acquisti();
    }



    private void annoAcquisti_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _acquisti.load(ref acquistiDGV, annoAcquisti.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: `_acquisti = new Acquisti();` should be under `InitializeComponent();` not at the bottom! Code executes sequentially (for the most part). So you are changing the `SelectedIndex` that will then try and use `_acquisti` before it is setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SelecteIndexChanged` is called due to line:

```
annoAcquisti.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

and you are initializing `_acquisti` after that. You can move the line before like:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _acquisti = new Acquisti(); //move it here
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

    for (int i = DateTime.Now.Year; i >= 2000; i--)
        annoAcquisti.Items.Add(i);

    annoAcquisti.SelectedIndex = 0;

}
```

Since the control moves to `SelectedIndexChanged` event and at that point `_acquisti` is still null, that is why you get the exception.

Answer (score 2):

> This means that SelectedIndexChanged event is called before than form constructor, isn't it?

No. It is called before the form constructor is FINISHED - as a result of actins in the constructor.

That is simple to fix - instead of playing around with the controls first initialize them and then play around.

Move the _Ackquisti = new.... line before the loop. Finishied.

In fact, initialization should happen first - before any further manipulation. InitializeCOmponent(), then other initialization, then more complicated stuff.